# What is the latest version of ROS that works with the Onboard DJI SDK

Tags: ros, dji-sdk

The documentation [here](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/github-platform-docs/ROS/README.html) says that you should use the Indigo version of ROS, but that version is set to end of life this month. Does anyone have experience with newer versions of ROS?

Answer (score 0):

Hi currently recommended distribution is [Melodic](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)

They are pretty similar the main difference is package compatibility I think.